# flask wtf forms errror

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am getting the following error from my terminal:
    `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}   File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 485, in getattr     return getattr(obj, attribute) jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined`

here is the related code:
(html template)

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.file }}
        {{ form.organs }}
        {{ form.upload }}
      
      </form>
```

python code:

```
class UploadImage(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField(validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['png', 'jpeg','jpg'], 'Images only!')]) #allow only files with the correct extension to be submitted
    organs = RadioField('Label', choices=[('leaf','leaf'),('flower','flower'),('fruit','fruit'),('bark','bark/stem')])
    upload = SubmitField("Upload")
```

````
#@login_required
def view_plants():
    #check if the file  the client wants to upload matches the specified requirements
    form = UploadImage()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        filename = secure_filename(form.file.data.filename)
        form.file.data.save('static/user_uploads/' + filename) #grab the file and save it in the uploads directory


        return render_template("your_plants.html")
    return render_template("your_plants.html")```
````

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing `form` to the template

Change your `render_templates` calls to this:

```
return render_template("your_plants.html", form=form)
```